# SQL - Finding any part of a long string inside a column in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a long string variable (e.g. `123456WALMARTabcdefghi   67815622 \\`). I have a table with two columns, `AccountNum` and `Account Name`.

`Account Name` contains 'Walmart' as one of the values. The `AccountNum` for that row is `78910`.

What SQL command would return the `AccountNum` of `78910`?

Edit: clarified that the `AccountNum` is not found in the long string variable.

This is the table that I'm trying to retrieve the `AccountNum` from.

| Account Num | Account Name |
| --- | --- |
| 78910 | Walmart |
| 111213 | Costco |

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CUSTOMER]
(
    [Account Num] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Account Name] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [RECID] [bigint] NOT NULL
) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

The expected output would be 78910 from the `AccountNum` column. I have tried various string commands (LIKE, CHARINDEX), but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Hi Ken, I added a table to the original question.

Comment: You forgot to add the table column definitions, the expected output,  and your effort to solve the problem yourself. You also need to add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality varies among them. Can you read the post I linked again?

Comment: Updated question with missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @WANTED AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @WANTED = "Walmart"

IF CHARINDEX(@WANTED,@yourVariable) > 0
begin
   SELECT AccountNum FROM table WHERE AccountName = @WANTED
end
else
    select 'Not Find' As Result
```